# QListWidget how to get the signal emitted?

Tags: python, pyqt

```
    with open('championships.txt', 'r') as rf:
        lines = rf.readlines()
        for line in lines:
            champioshiplist.addItem(QListWidgetItem(line.strip()))

    champioshiplist.doubleClicked.connect(self.listclisc)

def listclisc(self):
    print('OK')
```

I populated the Qwidgetlist from a txt file, but I am not able to get the clicked value from the list, in the example the printing works but how can i get text of the list ? I am not able to save the clicked item. i would like to do

```
    def listclisc(self):
      text = championshiplist.... value
```

but the function doesn't see the Qwidgetlist.  I am new in Python and do not really understand how to do

Answer (score 2):

The doubleClicked signal sends the associated QModelIndex that has the information you require:

```py
def listclisc(self, index):
    print('OK', index.data())
```

Similarly you can use the itemDoubleClicked signal:

```py
    champioshiplist.itemDoubleClicked.connect(self.listclisc)

def listclisc(self, item):
    print('OK', item.text())
```